# Old database with Related data, problem with my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a litte problem with my sql-query:

I have a old database (more than 30 Years old) with a table (test):

```
TABLE: *test*
ID   SNR    DATE
---------------------------
1     1     1911-11-11
2     1     1911-11-11
3     1     2019-04-17

4     2     1911-11-11
5     2     1911-11-11
6     2     1911-11-11

7     3     1911-11-11
8     3     1911-11-11
9     3     2017-01-20

10    4     1911-11-11
11    4     1911-11-11
12    4     1911-11-11

et cetera
```

Each record with the same SNR are related

for example:

ID 1,2,3 are Related AND
ID 4,5,6 are Related

I need the records where the Date is only 1911-11-11

for example:

SNR: 2 AND 4

my query:

SELECT * FROM `test` GROUP BY SNR AND DATE != 1911-11-11 ORDER BY ID

Is it possible to do this with a mysql query?

I hope you can help me

best regards

Comment: _Is it possible to do this with a mysql query?..._ Have you tried your query  to see what you get? - change it to `SELECT * FROM test WHERE  'DATE' != "1911-11-11" GROUP BY SNR ORDER BY ID` - here `DATE` is quoted because it is a reserved word

Comment: @B001ᛦ to quote `DATE` you should use backticks not single quotes...

Comment: Yes but backticks were used for the query comment. Thanks for mentioning @Nick

Comment: @B001ᛦ I don't think you got what I meant. Your query should have been `SELECT * FROM test WHERE \`DATE\` != "1911-11-11" GROUP BY SNR ORDER BY ID`

Answer (score 2):

You get the `snr`s that you want with this query:

```
select snr from test
group by snr
having sum(date = '1911-11-11') = count(*)
```

so use it as a subquery for your table:

```
select * from test
where snr in (
  select snr from test
  group by snr
  having sum(date = '1911-11-11') = count(*)
)
order by id
```

Comment: I was in the process of making a demo for an answer when you beat me to it, so here it is anyway https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oeWgXY2fQi92Mr4L9SS7Et/0